# Favorites Queries Folder

Tags: neo4j, favorites

I created several queries and saved them in a folder in Favorites.
After that I tried to experiment with authentication and as a result lost the folder. I.e. when I log in now I don't see it. 
I am hoping that the queries were saved in file somewhere, but can't find the file.
Am I right to assume that the queries are saved, and if I am, then where can I find the file?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The "Favorites" queries in the Neo4j Browser are stored using your web browser's LocalStorage and are not persisted to disk (as far as I know).

Try using the same browser / URL (i.e. http://localhost:7474) you used when you added them to the favorites to access again.

Comment: Thank you, William. I am using the same URL and the same user name neo4j.  Also, I believe the queries were persisted to disk, since I saw them after restarting my laptop multiple times.

Comment: You need to sue the same browser, check in the local storage for the page if you see them (in developer tools -> resources)